# How do I manage all my script tags in one place to be distributed across multiple HTML files in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Say I have the following HTML files:

```
index.html
about.html
contact.html
```

I want them all to load a list of scripts like the ones below:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridjs@4.0.0/dist/gridjs.production.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js" ></script>
```

But I don't want to have to go to each HTML file everytime I want to include a new library (I'm using Node.js by the way).

Any ideas?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: It's an … odd website where all those libraries would be useful on all the pages you mentioned.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file answering your qn ?